# hibernate envers: get modified entities for current revision

Tags: hibernate-envers, nhibernate-envers

In the current transaction, before committing, I want to see all changes for the current revision. I can get the current revision by doing :

```
auditReader.GetCurrentRevision<CustomRevisionEntity>(true)
```

The modifiedBy and revision number are correct. However the ModifiedEntityNames is null, although some entities were modified within this transaction. ModifiedEntityNames is the property that maps to the ENTITYNAME column of the REVCHANGES table

The below code returns an empty set:

```
 ISet<Tuple<string, Type>> modifiedEntityTypes = auditReader.CrossTypeRevisionChangesReader().FindEntityTypes(lastRevision.Value);
```

Is it not possible to retrieve modified entities before committing ?

Answer (score 1):

At least in the Java version, changes are written on a commit/flush.